# Randomly generated number

Tags: java

I am trying to make my own random number generator, but I was constantly getting the same values, I solved this with the sleep function, but how can I do without using sleep please help, I shared my code below.

My Random class

```
private int x;
private long ms;
public int random(int a) throws InterruptedException
{
    ms = System.currentTimeMillis();
    x=(int)(ms%a);
    Thread.sleep(1);
    return (int)x;
}
```

Main

```
 for(int i=0;i<100;i++)
    {
        System.out.println(rnd.random(10));
    }
```

Comment: "I am trying to make my own random number generator" Are you implying that you don't want to use `java.util.Random`?

Comment: The system time is not a random value. In fact, it’s very predictable to get the same number as long as the next call happens within the same millisecond. The imprecision of `sleep` is not a guaranteed behavior, on the next run or on a different computer you may again get the same values.

Comment: What about a `ThreadLocalRandom`?

Comment: If you are trying to implement a pseudorandom number generator _from scratch_, try one of [these](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_random_number_generators).

Comment: No one is actually answering the question.

Comment: The system time can be used to seed the generator but don't use it for anything else.

Comment: No one is answering because we don't know why you want to do this. If you just wanted to write a PRNG, there are lots of examples on the web. Your use of sleep() produces extremely bad numbers and is suspect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As has been stated, it won't be nearly as random as those methods provided by the Java API.  But try using:

```
System.nanoTime();
```

It changes more rapidly.

Note:  Writing a good RNG is non-trivial.  Check out [Random Number Generation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_number_generation) for more info.